# Working MDX query doesn't work as a Calculated Member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have made the following mdx query to calculate a running total using some references I found on internet which works when I ran it on management studio.

> With member measures.test
>   as
>
> (
>      sum([Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].[Calendar Year Month].&[2014]&>>[2014-10]
>              :[Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].CurrentMember
>              , [Measures].[LoyaltyMembers])
>   )
>
> select measures.test on 0,
>
> [Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].[Calendar Year Month] on 1
>
> from [SalesDW_v1]

But the following calculated member I constructed from this gives null values.

> CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Subscriptions Running Total]
>
> AS
>   (
>
> sum([Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].[Calendar Year Month].&[2014]&[2014-10]
>               :[Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].CurrentMember
>               , [Measures].[LoyaltyMembers])
>   )
>
> ,VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Demographics',FORMAT_STRING ="#,##0;-#,##0";

I would be glad, If someone could help me locate the problem.

Thank you very much,

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your member will work only for October, 2014, because of

```
[Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].[Calendar Year Month].&[2014]&[2014-10] :[Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].CurrentMember
```

Since you added it as calc member, when you add it from mdx designer, query gives null, if you also add time axis - it will show values for October till CurrentMember

You should avoid adding such members to cube UI, better embed them as report dataset query.

Comment: Indeed, when I replaced [Card Issue date].[YearQuarterMonth].[Calendar Year Month].&[2014]&[2014-10] with null it worked. Thanks